# Windows Kits errors

Tags: c, linker, makefile, declaration

I've managed to compile a C program, and now tried to link it with gcc (using makefile). But I get lots of errors from SetupAPI.h and commctrl.h, both from Winddows Kits 8.0. I'm using SDK 8.0, and am going to try with 7.0 and report back the results, may that be the case?

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
'__in_bcount' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2309, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in_ecount' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2883, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in_ecount' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2890, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in_ecount' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2897, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in_ecount' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2904, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in_opt' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2599, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in_opt' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2600, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in_opt' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2606, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2280, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2286, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2292, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2298, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2304, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2310, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2316, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2322, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2328, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2334, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2340, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2468, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2469, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2475, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2481, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2487, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2493, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2499, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2505, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2521, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2527, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2536, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2548, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2549, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2565, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2571, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2580, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2592, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2593, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2693, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2741, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2742, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2747, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2796, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2845, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2858, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2884, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2891, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2898, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2905, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2920, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2921, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2927, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2928, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2934, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2935, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2941, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2942, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2959, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2960, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2965, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2966, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2981, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2982, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2983, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2988, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2989, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 2990, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 3004, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 3005, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 3017, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 3018, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 3029, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 3030, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 3031, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 873, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 874, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 880, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 881, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 887, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 888, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 894, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__in' was not declared in this scope   exampleProg     line 895, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__inout_bcount' was not declared in this scope exampleProg     line 2279, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout_bcount' was not declared in this scope exampleProg     line 2285, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout_bcount' was not declared in this scope exampleProg     line 2291, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout_bcount' was not declared in this scope exampleProg     line 2297, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout_bcount' was not declared in this scope exampleProg     line 2303, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout_bcount' was not declared in this scope exampleProg     line 2315, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout_bcount' was not declared in this scope exampleProg     line 2321, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout_bcount' was not declared in this scope exampleProg     line 2327, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout_bcount' was not declared in this scope exampleProg     line 2333, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout_bcount' was not declared in this scope exampleProg     line 2339, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2457, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2462, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2467, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2474, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2480, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2486, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2492, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2498, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2504, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2510, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2515, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2520, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2526, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2535, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2547, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2554, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2559, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2564, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2570, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2579, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2591, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2598, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__inout' was not declared in this scope    exampleProg     line 2605, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__maybenull' does not name a type  exampleProg     line 2116, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__nullterminated' does not name a type exampleProg     line 353, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__nullterminated' does not name a type exampleProg     line 354, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__nullterminated' does not name a type exampleProg     line 355, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__nullterminated' does not name a type exampleProg     line 356, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__nullterminated' does not name a type exampleProg     line 357, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__nullterminated' does not name a type exampleProg     line 358, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__nullterminated' does not name a type exampleProg     line 359, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__nullterminated' does not name a type exampleProg     line 361, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__nullterminated' does not name a type exampleProg     line 362, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__nullterminated' does not name a type exampleProg     line 363, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__nullterminated' does not name a type exampleProg     line 364, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__nullterminated' does not name a type exampleProg     line 421, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__nullterminated' does not name a type exampleProg     line 422, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__nullterminated' does not name a type exampleProg     line 423, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__nullterminated' does not name a type exampleProg     line 424, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__nullterminated' does not name a type exampleProg     line 425, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__nullterminated' does not name a type exampleProg     line 427, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__nullterminated' does not name a type exampleProg     line 428, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__out_ecount_full' was not declared in this scope  exampleProg     line 2882, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__out_ecount_full' was not declared in this scope  exampleProg     line 2889, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__out_ecount_full' was not declared in this scope  exampleProg     line 2896, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__out_ecount_full' was not declared in this scope  exampleProg     line 2903, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__out_ecount_full' was not declared in this scope  exampleProg     line 2919, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__out_ecount_full' was not declared in this scope  exampleProg     line 2926, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__out_ecount_full' was not declared in this scope  exampleProg     line 2933, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__out_ecount_full' was not declared in this scope  exampleProg     line 2940, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__out' was not declared in this scope  exampleProg     line 3006, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__out' was not declared in this scope  exampleProg     line 3019, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__possibly_notnullterminated' does not name a type exampleProg     line 366, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__possibly_notnullterminated' does not name a type exampleProg     line 367, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__possibly_notnullterminated' does not name a type exampleProg     line 368, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__possibly_notnullterminated' does not name a type exampleProg     line 369, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__possibly_notnullterminated' does not name a type exampleProg     line 430, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__possibly_notnullterminated' does not name a type exampleProg     line 431, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'__post' does not name a type   exampleProg     line 1201, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'__post' does not name a type   exampleProg     line 2270, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'_InterlockedAdd' declared as an 'inline' variable  exampleProg     line 2535, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'_InterlockedAdd64' declared as an 'inline' variable    exampleProg     line 2579, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'Count' was not declared in this scope  exampleProg     line 2882, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'Count' was not declared in this scope  exampleProg     line 2883, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'Count' was not declared in this scope  exampleProg     line 2889, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'Count' was not declared in this scope  exampleProg     line 2890, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'Count' was not declared in this scope  exampleProg     line 2896, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'Count' was not declared in this scope  exampleProg     line 2897, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'Count' was not declared in this scope  exampleProg     line 2903, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'Count' was not declared in this scope  exampleProg     line 2904, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'Count' was not declared in this scope  exampleProg     line 2919, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'Count' was not declared in this scope  exampleProg     line 2926, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'Count' was not declared in this scope  exampleProg     line 2933, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'Count' was not declared in this scope  exampleProg     line 2940, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'EXCEPTION_ROUTINE' does not name a type    exampleProg     line 1212, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'LPCSTR' does not name a type   exampleProg     line 472, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'LPSTR' does not name a type    exampleProg     line 471, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h   C/C++ Problem
'MultiplyExtract128' declared as an 'inline' variable   exampleProg     line 3029, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'Offset' was not declared in this scope exampleProg     line 2279, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'Offset' was not declared in this scope exampleProg     line 2285, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'Offset' was not declared in this scope exampleProg     line 2291, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'Offset' was not declared in this scope exampleProg     line 2297, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'Offset' was not declared in this scope exampleProg     line 2303, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'Offset' was not declared in this scope exampleProg     line 2309, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'Offset' was not declared in this scope exampleProg     line 2315, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem
'Offset' was not declared in this scope exampleProg     line 2321, external location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\winnt.h  C/C++ Problem   
etc.
```

EDIT: Chnaging to SDK 7 got rid third of the errors. Error log above is updated accordinglly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compile the Windows kit headers directly with gcc. You can only use the supplied nmake/msbuild toolchain.

Most of the errors you see com from a missing include file contents of sal.h. I have no idea why sal.h is not automatically included.

Note that there is a gcc distribution which contains a gcc friendly version of the windows headers, which is called mingw.

Comment: I'm using MinGW. I'll try adding sal.h to the file tomorrow and report back. Strange thing is though, this program should compile as is - I only want to add wrapper functions for Java.

Comment: If you are using mingw, you have to use the accompanied windows header files, and cannot use the windows sdk headers.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. The thing is I've included Windows SDK because of the errors I got. I guess the problem is in writing the Makefile. I'm haveing trouble with this specifc case (among others): 

first.c : 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "../../include/libusbcom/usbcom.h"

second.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "../../include/libusbcom/usbcom.h"

third.h: /

fourth:
#include <windows.h>
#include <winusb.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <usb.h>
#include <SetupAPI.h>

Comment: fourth.h:
#ifdef LIBFOURTH_EXPORTS
#define FOURTH_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define FOURTH_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#ifndef _WINDOWS
#undef FOURTH_API
#define FOURTH_API
#endif
How should I write makefile for this? One of my attempts was like this:

fourth.dll: fourth.o
 $(LINK_CMD)
  
fourth.o : second.c fourth.h third.h
 $(COMP_CMD) -DLIBUSBCOM_EXPORTS -D_WINDOWS

first.dll: first.o
 $(LINK_CMD)
  
first.o : first.c fourth.h third.h
 $(COMP_CMD) -DLIBUSBCOM_EXPORTS -D_WINDOWS

And second one was the same exapt for the first line:

fourth.dll: fourth.o first.o
 $(LINK_CMD)

Comment: I guess it would be best to re-ask this new question with mingw in title. Maybe someone with knowledge of mingw can help you. (Sorry, I can't ...)